# How to eliminate special characters(&#x0d) in xml format of the result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

While converting the query result set into xml format in TSQL,it shows '&#x0d' in the line end.kindly help me to eliminate this.

Actually I am using the following query to get slow queries,

```
SELECT top 10 qs.execution_count Exec_count, 
(qs.total_elapsed_time / qs.execution_count )/ 1000000.0 AS Avg_exec_time,
convert(datetime2(0),qs.last_execution_time) Last_exec_time,
SUBSTRING(st.text, (qs.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,
((CASE statement_end_offset
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
ELSE qs.statement_end_offset END
- qs.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS Query
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) st
ORDER BY Avg_exec_time DESC for xml path('slow_query')
```

The example result set:(I just picked some lines from the output)

```
> @queue_agent, &#x0D;
>             msqh.runstatus, &#x0D;
>             msqa.id,&#x0D;
>             msqa.name,&#x0D;
```

Comment: Don't use `FOR XML` if you do not need/want the `XML` node values to be escaped.

Comment: For me, in Power BI with a DirectQuery in model view that threw an error like 'the visualisation cannot be shown' (German: "Die Visualisierung kann nicht angezeigt werden"), it turned out that it was not thrown by the linebreaks, but by the too long text, I had to truncate the column live in TSQL at roughly 600 characters to make it run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite sure, what your problem is actually...

`&x0D;` is the entity code for a carriage return (a line break)

You must distinguish between data **within XML** and data **you read out of XML**.

Within XML many characters need to be escaped, as the would have a special semantic otherwise. If you see this code **within** XML everything should be okay...

If you read data out of XML the question is: How are you doing this? If this is done properly, all this encoding and re-encoding should be done implicitly...

If this does not help you, please provide more details...

### UPDATE

As a *quick shot* you could use `REPLACE(YourString,CHAR(13),'')` to get rid of these characters **before** you create the XML...

### UPDATE 2

Still I do not get the point, why this is important for you...

As you know for sure, there are several ways to encode a linebreak. But in all cases this is just one (or two) special characters. Whether they are **presented** as visible line break or not is an issue for the tool you are using to read the data.

Check this out (in SSMS):

```
SELECT 
'
' AS VisibleLineBreak
,CHAR(10) AS LineFeed
,CHAR(13) AS CarriagReturn
,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) AS NewLine
,CHAR(10)+CHAR(13) AS WrongOrder
FOR XML PATH('LineBreaks');
```

The visible result in the grid-output

```
<LineBreaks><VisibleLineBreak>&#x0D;</VisibleLineBreak><LineFeed>&#x0A;</LineFeed><CarriagReturn>&#x0D;</CarriagReturn><NewLine>&#x0D;</NewLine></LineBreaks>
```

But if you click the XML "link" in order to open the XML viewer you get this

```
<LineBreaks>
  <VisibleLineBreak>
    </VisibleLineBreak>
  <LineFeed>
</LineFeed>
  <CarriagReturn>
</CarriagReturn>
  <NewLine>
</NewLine>
  <WrongOrder>

</WrongOrder>
</LineBreaks>
```

The result with *output to text* is

```
<LineBreaks><VisibleLineBreak>&#x0D;
    </VisibleLineBreak><LineFeed>&#x0A;</LineFeed><CarriagReturn>&#x0D;</CarriagReturn><NewLine>&#x0D;
</NewLine><WrongOrder>
&#x0D;</WrongOrder></LineBreaks>
```

The most usual "NewLine" (13+10 or 0A+0D) is given with a written `x0D` but an executed `x0A`, while the explicit `x0A` is written *as is*...

What I want to say with this: **Do not bother about encodings *within* XML. This is *not* meant for human reading!**. The reading application must bother about the proper **presentation** of these special characters!

Comment: actually @shnugo the above script I mentioned is used to get slow queries  in xml format.The script gives the correct result set in SSMS.But while I running it in TSQL it shows &x0D; in end of the line.How to eliminate this?

Comment: Kindly run the above db script in your local server environment.Then you will get the point what I am coming to say.

Comment: How can I achieve it throug TSQL

Comment: @SujithTee Sorry, I do not understand *How can I achieve it throug TSQL*... The above code is TSQL and you can see clearly, that it is not the query's result set responsible for these characters, but the way you look at it (so: the *reading* tool). There's nothing wrong with `&#x0D;` as long as this is **within** XML...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but short and simple to answer the question:
add REPACE() into the column containing the special characters.

```
SELECT top 10 qs.execution_count Exec_count, 
(qs.total_elapsed_time / qs.execution_count )/ 1000000.0 AS Avg_exec_time,
convert(datetime2(0),qs.last_execution_time) Last_exec_time,
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(st.text, (qs.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,
((CASE statement_end_offset
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
ELSE qs.statement_end_offset END
- qs.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1),'&#x0d','') AS Query
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) st
ORDER BY Avg_exec_time DESC for xml path('slow_query')
```